# Add Twitter into iframe

Tags: html, iframe, twitter

I want to create a page having twitter in an iframe, but I wasn't able to open the site by simply setting the attribute src to http://www.twitter.com/ 
So, how to add twitter in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no policy changes Twitter not allowing to put its website on iframe.